# View perl module install error AFTER installed

Tags: perl, cpan

When installing Perl modules (prerequisites for another program), some module showed me an incompatibility warning and said something about needing to downgrade a package.  I thought I would get back to that later.

Now I want to review the warning to figure out what package I need to downgrade - but the text has scrolled too far back.  How can I get that warning back?  Is there a CPAN command that will check compatibility of all installed modules and print out warnings?

And, is there a simple way to downgrade a package to ensure compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what specific warning you have seen and where it came from. But there is no generic mechanism to produce these warnings - if it come from a Perl module it is an individual way done by the specific module. Therefore there is  also no way to get these warnings back or check compatibility between all installed perl modules.

There is also no easy way to uninstall a module with all the dependencies which might have been installed to or to downgrade a module. That's why Linux distributions typically have package managers which handle such dependencies for the shipped modules - so it is preferred to use these if possible instead of CPAN. You might try to uninstall a module using the instructions in [How to cleanly uninstall a Perl module](https://www.perl.com/article/3/2013/3/27/How-to-cleanly-uninstall-a-Perl-module/) (look at the end of the article, where it shows the easy way with `cpanm`) and reinstall it again though - but this does nothing with the dependencies.

Comment: The warnings was similar too: this module may be incompatible with module XXXX later than version X.XX.  If this module doesn't work as expected downgrade XXXX